# What is wrong with this sentence? I can't figure it out

Tags: sentence

What is wrong with this sentence?

> If you cause any trouble to him, I’ll not tolerate that.

Comment: Wrongly placed objects. *If you cause him any trouble, I'll not tolerate that*.

Comment: It's not fluent contemporary American English, for many reasons. It's marked as 'foreign', in the sense that a native speaker wouldn't say it that way. Nothing wrong with that, just noted as different, that's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with cause. You don't cause something *to* someone, you cause someone something (like trouble or harm), or cause something *for* someone.
You could either say:

> If you cause him any trouble,

Or:

> If you cause any trouble for him,

Check out the different uses and more examples in these dictionaries:

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/cause)

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cause)

Answer (score -1):

Your sentence has contradictory tenses.

I'll not tolerate any trouble you'll cause to him. (this sounds proper)

Comment: Why change the conditional? Isn't that type 1 conditional? It doesn't sound wrong to me...it's like saying "If you touch him I'll kill you" that doesn't sound wrong

Comment: If you touch him I'll kill you. is all in the future tense. The tenses are future.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong either. But I was told it was wrong.

Comment: If you cause any trouble to him is implying future tense

Comment: I'll not tolerate that is implying past tense. Tenses contradict.

Comment: "I'll not tolerate that" is past tense? I don't get it.

Comment: It's implying that the event (the trouble caused) has already occurred.